# Firefox Addon PKCS#11 API

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, pkcs#11

I want to access the currenly connected cryptography modules via an Firefox Addon.

I found some interfaces that look like i can access the module, the slot and the token ([1](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/public/nsIPKCS11ModuleDB.idl) → [2](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/public/nsIPKCS11Module.idl) → [3](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/public/nsIPKCS11Slot.idl) → [4](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/public/nsIPK11Token.idl)) but how can i access the public key of an certificate stored on such a token?

Is there an such an API even available to an Addon?

Comment: [nsIX509CertDB.idl](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/public/nsIX509CertDB.idl) looks promising to me, i will look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nsIX509CertDB.idl](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/nsIX509CertDB.idl) provides the means to access all stored certificates, therefore also the ones accessed through crypto modules. To filter the certificates using the tokenName property should work.

Here is a snippet to enumerate all certs:

```
var certDB = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/security/x509certdb;1"].getService(chrome.Ci.nsIX509CertDB);

var certs = certDB.getCerts();

var enumerator = certs.getEnumerator();

var s = "";
while (enumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
  var cert = enumerator.getNext().QueryInterface(chrome.Ci.nsIX509Cert);

  if (cert.tokenName.equals("Your-token-name"))   
  s += cert.tokenName + " # ";
}
```

The name of the token can be found through the module name by using: [nsIPKCS11ModuleDB.listModules()](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/nsIPKCS11ModuleDB.idl) → [nsIPKCS11Module.listSlots()](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/nsIPKCS11Module.idl) → [nsIPKCS11Slot.getToken()](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/nsIPKCS11Slot.idl) → [nsIPK11Token.tokenName](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/nsIPK11Token.idl)