# Working with certificates in Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, certificate, firefox-addon-sdk, ca

I would like to ask whether it is possible to work with CA certificates through addon and legacy extension. I do not need complicated features, only authorize or refuse certificates. That the user can through this addon to edit the list of CA certificates.

For example: A user would all CA certificates canceled and servers and allow only one certificate, for example a bank.

> Previous question :
>
> I would ask if you can work with the certificates in Firefox via an
> add-on SDK API. My job would be an add-on, where the user can select
> the certificates that will use firefox. I would like to do two or
> three categories of certificates (normal, important), and based on the
> add-on in Firefox to use one or the other group certificates.
>
> For starters, my work, I would like especially to ask for some
> references on this issue and whether it is possible to create
> something like that, thank you very much.

Comment: I found [nsIX509CertDB.idl](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/nsIX509CertDB.idl) documentation, which partially helped me.

Comment: I finished my add-on. 

More about interfaces certificates [Firefox Addon PKCS#11 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817166/firefox-addon-pkcs11-api/28836473#28836473)